How to get Firebase Auth ID Token in server component in nextjs firebase?
I am creating a server side component in nextjs 14 (app router). now I want current user id (Firebase Authentication) in this Server Side Component.
To get UID I have to send ID Token to backend and get UID. (documentation).
Now I want ID Token :
To get ID Token in client side we have this way.
But I cannot find any way to get ID Token in Server Side Component
I think firebase SDK already store ID token in cookies. If this is true, how to get it?
another way is to set ID Token in cookie and and get it in Server Side Component. like this :-
        onAuthStateChanged(auth, async (response) => {
            if (response) {
                const token = await response.getIdToken();
                setCookies(token); 
            } 
        });

Now my question is what is best way to get Firebase Auth ID Token in Server Side Component in Next.js 14?
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Backends (and server side components) can't use the frontend web SDK to get the current user.  You have to arrange to send an ID token to the backend from your frontend if you want to tell it who the current user is for any given call.  You will need to use the Firebase Admin SDK to validate the token.  See the documentation for details.

@DougStevenson how can I get ID token? so that I can send it to backend.

@DougStevenson I can get ID token in client-side by following  link. but how can I get in server side component?

Send the token as you would any other piece of data you want to send to a SSR.  It's just a string.

@DougStevenson Sir, I understood that to get UID I have to send ID Token to Backend and get uid. Now how to get ID Token so that I can send this piece of string to backend? hope you understand my concern.

Use the documentation that I linked in my first comment, or read through the answers in the duplicate questions that I marked.
